# Find min and maxima

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, optimization

Find local min and maxima of $ \sin(x^3)$ on the interval $]-2,2[$.

I take the derivative and get:

$$3x^2 \cdot \cos (x^3)$$

I set this equal to zero and get $$x^3 = \cos^{-1}(0)$$

$$ \Rightarrow x^3 = \frac{\pi}{2}+k \cdot \pi$$

I'm not sure what the easiest way to proceed from here would be? Taking the third root confuses me more than just keeping it on this format..I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the derivative equal to zero gives you $$3x^2\cdot\cos(x^3)=0$$
and this is zero only when $x=0$ or $\cos(x^3)=0$.

$x=0$ can't be a local minimum, because $\sin(x^3)$ is an odd function, so it remains to solve $\cos(x^3)=0$ on $]\!-\!2,2[$.

Note that $\cos^{-1} t$ has a specific meaning, it's the inverse of $\cos t$ restricted to $[0,\pi]$. So just say that $\cos t=0$ for $\displaystyle t=\frac\pi2+k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$ and you want to solve
$$x^3=\frac\pi2+k\pi$$
on $]\!-\!2,2[$. But $x^3$ is one-to-one and transforms that interval into $]\!-\!8,8[$. Can you find all values of $k$ such that $\displaystyle\frac\pi2+k\pi\in\ ]\!-\!8,8[$ ?

Comment: Can you detail better how "$x^3$ transforms the interval" and what does it mean exactly that $sin$ is an odd function? I'm seeing it has something to do with distance from x being the same?

Comment: @Paze You only really need that $x^3$ is increasing, so $-2<x<2\Longrightarrow -8<x^3<-8$. Your $x=\sqrt[3]{\frac\pi2+k\pi}$ is in $]\!-\!2,2[$ only if $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ is in $]\!-\!8,8[$. Odd function means that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$. So $\sin(x)>0$ on $(0,\pi)$ implies $\sin(x)<0$ on $(-\pi,0)$ and there clearly can't be a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to compute any derivative: the expression is maximum when
$$
x^3 = \frac\pi 2 + n\pi, n\in\Bbb Z.
$$

Comment: nice and simple

Answer (score 0):

Because it is $ \sin$  of something ($ \sin(X)$) the minimum is always -1 and the maximum is +1.

[image]

As you can see in this interval it has exactly 3 minimums and 3 maximums if the interval is closed and 2 if the interval is open like in your case.

Comment: We are working on the open interval so only 2 minimums and 2 maximums.

Comment: yes, right. I edit my post.